# Query request to IP range

Tags: jquery, ip, range

I need to send a request to an IP range.

Problem:
Only `192.168.0.200` receives the request.

Example of code:

```
for(var i=100;i<=200;i++)
{
   var query='http://admin:admin@192.168.0.'+i+'/cgi-bin/devVideoInput.cgi?action=autoFocus';
   $('#ifr').attr('src', query);
}
```

Comment: You are overriding the `attr` every reiteration. What is your expected output?

Comment: I need to send request to each ip.

Comment: How do you send request to each ip? on your code you are just changing the src attribute of `#ifr`

Comment: I need send request, change src...send request, change src, etc...
But in my example, only last ip recieve request.

Comment: How do you send the request? Do you click the link? Send ajax request?

Comment: When I loading page, request is sending

Comment: `#ifr` is a link? or an iframe?

Comment: <iframe src="" id=ifr></iframe>

Comment: Then you have to make 100 iframes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
for(var i=100;i<=200;i++)
{
   var query='http://admin:admin@192.168.0.'+i+'/cgi-bin/devVideoInput.cgi?action=autoFocus';

jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'foo'+i    
}).appendTo('#ifr');

$('#foo'+i).load(query);
console.log('loading '+query+'onto div with id foo'+i);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ifr"></div>
```

I suggest you to use multiple div to load because the loading takes time and you keep overwriting on the same div.